# MySQL - Inner join into same table with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL table called **campaigns** like the following

```
ID    integer
Name  text
isBalanced  boolean
redirects  tinyint
```

I am trying to achieve a SELECT query so that I get ALL the rows where `isBalanced` is false PLUS only a DEFINED number of rows where `isBalanced` is true. After I get this result I need to get the single one with the lowest number of `redirects`.

I know that there are ways to do it but I am having an hard time to figure out how. This is what I got until know

```
SELECT campaigns.id, campaigns.name, campaigns.isBalanced, campaigns.redirects
FROM campaigns AS c
INNER JOIN campaigns_2 AS c2
WHERE c.isBalanced = 0
```

However I am not able to select just some of them from the c2 set and then regroup all the filter to get the single one with lowest number of `redirects`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show some sample data and the expected result.it is not clear what you need.

Comment: What is your "defined" number of rows? Are these IDs in a table? Some criteria? Also, don't think in terms of "I want these rows, then I want to get this one from those". SQL is set-based and you need to teach yourself to think in those terms and not in sequential processing terms.

Comment: @TomH yes and no, SQL is also kind of sequential. E.g. when you select from a sub query you can look at it as a 2-step process. Also things like IN or EXISTS (or even WHERE itself) can be viewed as a sequential step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want `union all`, perhaps with `order by` and `limit`:

```
select c.*
from campaigns c
where c.isBalanced = 0
union all
(select c.*
 from campaigns c
 where c.isBalanced = 1
 limit ??
)
order by redirects
limit 1;
```

The "defined number" goes where the `??` is.

Comment: you don't need `UNION ALL` here, just `UNION`

Comment: @Stan . . . `UNION ALL` is always preferable to `UNION`, unless you specifically want to incur the overhead of removing duplicate values.

Comment: This is it, @GordonLinoff. Thank you very much.